# SharePoint 2013 List Workflow with Custom Field

Tags: sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, custom-field-types

I am currently working with a SharePoint 2013 List Workflow (SPD Workflow).

On my list, I have a custom field called 'Image', which allows user to upload image from the list directly, without needing to upload the image somewhere.

The problem is, when I tried to create a SPD workflow for item approval, the start task process always failed and returned exception:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation
```

After I checked further into the log, I found the innerException of that error:

```
The field 'Image' is in a field collection that cannot be updated, such as one returned as part of a query
```

Is there any workaround on this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What about letting the people upload a picture via attachment?

Comment: Had proposed it before, but the business requirement is to upload image only files, and preview them in the form. So I don't think the attachment field would help in this case.